# Не работает иерархическое отображение в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Создана вот такая структура пакетов - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы она представлялась в таком виде - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В package explore уже проставлял иерархический вид, это никакого влияния вообще не оказало на представление проекта.
Также менял представление с Java на JavaEE(Default) и обратно, результат также отрицательный.

Comment: а у вас все классы только в "последнем" пакете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman
Пока да, пакет be хранит пакет с единственным классом. Но потом мне нужно будет добавить в be еще пару пакетов которые также будут содержать пакеты с классами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выключите опцию **Flat** в **Package Presentation**